# Installing Kubuntu 17.04 X64 on GTX960 - black screen without nomodeset, white screen with nomodeset

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, 17.04

After booting from DVD I get a black screen. When I added parameters `xforcevesa` and `nomodeset` the screen is white. The situation is the same whether I enable UEFI or disable UEFI.

Any help?

Comment: If you have a desktop, and try physically removing the Nvidia card and installing using the Intel graphics